# hide and show WKInterfaceGroup programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm using xCode 6.2 beta 2 and tried to hide and show group programmatically but there is no method shown where i can write `group.hidden=YES` or `group.hidden=NO`
Is there any another method for doing same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is no property for hide group in WKInterfaceGroup.
But there is same property available in WkInterfaceObject which is super class of WKInterfaceGroup.

so you can do same like
`[group setHidden:YES]`
or
`[group setHidden=NO]`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a swift you can use this code:

```
 mygroup.setHidden(true)// set true --> false if you want to show the group
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it this way:

```
[group setHidden:YES];
```

In WatchKit you can't access properties with the dot notation.